# Domino Data Service - get document(s) by searching with field value

Tags: httprequest, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, get-request, ibm-domino

I tried everything, but it woudn't work, I knew there are some similar questions out there with answers, but the questions were asked 5 years ago and aren't up to date and arent't working.

My Question is: How can I search for field values by using the Domino Data Service Rest-Api.

The url I am using: **GET http(s)://{database}/api/data/documents?search=[fieldname]%20CONTAINS%20VALUE**

This URl doesn't work. I get always an error.

**Error:**

```
"code":400,
"text":"Bad Request",
"message":"Database is not full text indexed.",
"type":"text",
"data":"com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException: Database is not full text indexed.\r\n\tat...
```

**thanks in advance!**

Comment: "message":"Database is not full text indexed."... the error message is self explanatory: you need the admin to create a full text index on the database to be able to search...

Comment: Adding to what @Torsten said, creating a full-text index is as easy as clicking a button (for someone with the proper access.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Notes desktop or Domino Designer, open the **Database Properties** for the database.  Click on the Search tab:

[image: Document Properties box Search tab]

Click the **Create Index** button to create the index, or find an administrator who has permission to do it.